# Change div position by time

Tags: jquery, css

I want to change my **div**'s top and left position every 200ms, why doesn't this code work?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
        //$('#quatao').css("top", "+=20"); it's work!!!!
        if (parseInt($("#quatao").css("top"),10) < 350) { 
             $("#quatao").css("top", "+=20", "left", "-=30");
         }
         else if (parseInt($("#quatao").css("top"),10) > 500) {
             $("#quatao").css("top", "-=20", "left", "+=30");
         }
    }, 200);
});
```

Comment: I think you should also mention units like `px`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see just by looking at the code, you should use objects instead of a comma list inside of the $("...").css calls.

```
$("#quatao").css({"top": "+=20", "left": "-=30"});

$("#quatao").css({"top": "-=20", "left": "+=30"});
```

Note, when only one value is to be changed, comma separation works, but for two or more values, a json-object is needed.

[Check out different usages for .css here](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Answer (score 0):

You must have initially set the top position on CSS, else '$("#quatao").css("top")' should return 'auto' instead of a number.

It could be simple as:

```
<div id="quatao" style="top:0px;left:0px"></div>
```

Check if this is what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/8g1Lzr5c/1/

Comment: No, inline style is not the way to go. This information might suit in a css file though, but the question mentions nothing about initial state.

Comment: Although there is a logic problem in this code, as soon as the top reaches 360px the div would stop moving. But i don't know the author's objective with it.